# Why does the following Toggle function perform four different operations instead of two?

Tags: jquery, html, css

You can see the implementation here: http://jsfiddle.net/BMWZd/8/

What I am trying to do, when you click on 'John Brown', you see the first element at top turn black. When you click it again, the border of the dotted circle disappears, then when you click 'John Brown' again, you see something else, then finally once again it all disappears.

What I am trying to achieve is when you click it once, everything turns black (like it does now), then you click it again, everything disappears and goes back to the original state.

Important distinction, what I mean is...when one of the names in the box are not clicked. So if you clicked John Brown then moved to Jack Dorsey, the #1 at top should stay black. But if you were to click Jack Dorsey again, i.e. you 'unclicked' it, then it should disappear.

Also, how do I tighten it up, so that it responds quicker. Now when you click it, it feels like there is a little bit of a lag between when it was clicked and when it responds.

Edit1: If anyone is interested...the UI that this will be used in is for my webapp - http://www.compversions.com

Comment: That's a pretty cool use of the border-radius property.

Comment: By the way, [table abuse](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/)? Ewww.

Comment: SO questions should stand on their own.  This requires a third party resource to understand the question.

Comment: @tster, I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @marcamillion, It would be impossible to understand or answer this question without visiting your jsfiddle link.  SO questions should stand on their own as third party websites might not be around a month from now, or the URL link on that site could break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/timmywil/BMWZd/23/  I only made steps one and two work.  I'm sure you can take it from there.

Comment: Dude...I could KISS you :) This works PERFECTLY. Thanks meng.

Answer (score 1):

The first toggle function runs every other click, so you add/remove `.dash-elem-selected` and `.bc-dotted-to-solid` every other click. Two `.dash-elem-selected`, followed by two off, plus solid/dotted borders every other click gives you four states. Since you're already using separate functions, have one add classes (i.e. set the "on" state) and the other remove them (i.e. set the "off" state).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#panels tr table tr').toggle(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            tr_class = 'dash-elem-selected';
        if (!$this.parent('thead').length) {
            $this.addClass(tr_class).siblings().removeClass(tr_class);
            var idx = $.trim($this.parents('td table').siblings('.sit-in-the-corner').text());
            var spans = $('#bc' + idx + ' span');
            spans.addClass('bc-dotted-to-solid');
            spans.filter('.dashed-circle').css({ 'border' : '5px solid #000'});
        }
    }, function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var idx = $.trim($this.parents('td table').siblings('.sit-in-the-corner').text());
        var spans = $('#bc' + idx + ' span');
        spans.removeClass('bc-dotted-to-solid');
        spans.filter('.dashed-circle').css({ 'border' : '5px dotted #bdbebf' });
    });
});
```

The `.dash-elem-selected` class needs a `color: black` (or somesuch, but that's in line with the rest of the design), to show that a particular item has been selected.

Comment: Actually one of the problems with this, is in the synchronization between the two elements. You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/A9Su4/1/ If you click one element, then click another, then click another, and keep clicking another...after a while, the top dashed circle will toggle off. Even though it should never, because once you keep pressing a name, #1 box will be 'active'. Also, once you click John Brown, the text doesn't change color like it should to indicate that it is active.